# How to add a customer file in the git folder

Tags: git, github

I have downloaded a code from github as

```
git clone https://github.com/askmike/gekko.git
```

And I changed to develop branch as

```
git checkout origin/develop
```

Now, I am in develop branch that can be known by

```
git status
HEAD detached at origin/develop
nothing to commit, working directory clean
```

I will add a new file to the folder gekko such as `configure_customer.js`. If the next time the develop branch update, I just use

```
git pull
```

However, it often detects that `configure_customer.js` is new file and I must use `git add configure_customer.js` to do add it to the project. Then, I command `git pull` again and my file is lost. Which step did I missing? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to commit your change and push it to the server:

```
git add --all # or `git add <file>`
git commit
# Type the commit message and save
git push origin develop
```

In case you want to add all your new files, `git add --all` is better, while `git add .` will only add new files in your current working directory, if it happens not to be the root directory of the repository.

Comment: But I have no permission to add it to the server of project. Did you mean I will commit to my github account

Comment: @Jame Essentially, YES.

Comment: I used it but I got the error when I used push `remote: Permission to askmike/gekko.git denied to John1231983.
fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/askmike/gekko.git/': The requested URL returned error: 403`

Comment: @Jame You need write access to the target repository, or you can fork it and make your own one.

Comment: I see. So first I need to fork it to my account. Then I download it and do as your suggestion. But, If the develop branch in the askmike account update, does it also update in my branch? Thanks

Comment: It means I need to delete current project which forked before and do fork again?

Comment: @Jame No you don't need to. You can fork updates and integrate into your repository.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add and commit the file, followed by pushing your branch. And after that, you should do `git pull`

```
git add configure_customer.js
git commit configure_customer.js -m "some message here"
git push origin develop
git pull
```

In case, you want to add all new files, you should use

```
git add .
git commit . -m "commit message here"
```